# "Your browser is being managed by your organization" what is this message?

Tags: tails, malware, internet-service-provider

**Is my ISP watching me?**
*"Your browser is being managed by your organization"* appeared on Tor preferences.
I have taken no security measures other than what TailsOS already has. Is there any way I can deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

**You can safely disregard the message:**

> All this message means is that the automatic updates feature of Tor Browser has been disabled. This is done intentionally in Tails to make sure that no security feature or configuration gets broken by automatic updates of Tor Browser.

Source: [Tails documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/anonymous_internet/Tor_Browser)

Answer (score 0):

No, you're fine: it's because Tails is still too immature to do things properly that even a Tor browser is too tough for them. If you want a full protection - use QubesOS